# ZSH alternative to BASH export VAR+='...'

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I'm a Zsh user and I've encountered a problem I don't fully know how to solve:

- If I  append an env variable within my `zshrc` [`BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE`], which works in Bash, I receive a parsing error:

  ```bash
  export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE+=' CCACHE_DEPEND CCACHE_SLOPPINESS ICECC_REMOTE_CPP
  ```

  ```bash
  /home/dev/.zshrc:export:139: not valid in this context:
  BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE+
  ```
- I tried fixing this by changing the `export` command to the below, which helped to correctly set the variable, but now when I source my `zshrc` multiple times, I get repeated values in the variable, which I don't want:

  ```bash
  export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="${BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE} CCACHE_DEPEND CCACHE_SLOPPINESS ICECC_REMOTE_CPP"
  ```

I'm looking for a solution that will append to the variable but won't do so every time I source my `zshrc` if I added an alias, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can almost certainly just do

```
BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE+=' CCACHE_DEPEND CCACHE_SLOPPINESS ICECC_REMOTE_CPP'
```

If it is an environment variable, the export flag well likely already be set. You could also add a separate `export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE` command if that really might not be the case.

There is nothing intrinsic to the bash syntax that is avoiding duplicates. Where are you setting the variable for bash? Perhaps use `.zlogin` perhaps instead of `.zshrc` to only have it set for the initial login. The other common way is to set environment variables in `.zshenv` but only within an `if` condition that checks things like `$SHLVL` to avoid running in subshells, I often use:

```
if [[ ! -o login && ! -o privileged && -o rcs && $SHLVL = 1 ]]; then
```

The `-o login` test in there may be removed - it depends.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine using an array, you can stick to the `+=` syntax.

Here is an example:

```
# define the array (-a) to hold only unique values (-U)
typeset -U -a foo_array

# initial values
foo_array=(one two three)

# print the content
print -l $foo_array
 one
 two
 three

# add values
foo_array+="one"
foo_array+="four"
foo_array+=(two five)

# recheck the array
print -l $foo_array
 one
 two
 three
 four
 five
```

Notice that the repeatedly added values do not show up multiple times, because we used `-U` in the declaration!

You can use the array either as `$foo_array` (behaves as if the values are single arguments) or as `"$foo_array"` (behaves as if the values are stitched together to a single string separated by blanks):

```
$ printf "%s|" $foo_array
one|two|three|four|five|

$ printf "%s|" "$foo_array"
one two three four five|
```